# Additional persistence layer in roo

Tags: persistence, spring-roo

I have created a roo project following the typical persistence setup instructions resulting in a Hibernate and Hypersonic in-memory data layer. I was wondering how it's possible to add another, say Hibernate and PostgreSQL, persistence layer with the ability to switch between both, using one for development and the other for production.

Thanks,
Sammy

Answer (score 0):

When Spring 3.1 comes out you will be able to define the beans by region - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1876.  Investigate using Maven Profiles to assist with switching - http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html

Hope this helps.
Gordon Dickens
twitter.com/gdickens
technophileblog.gordondickens.com